# How we can run more than one feature files and all feature files depending on the requirement using same runner class?

Tags: karate

1. I have 5 feature files I want to run some feature files depends on the requirement using one runner class only is it possible and if then how?

Answer (score 1):

1) You can run required feature adding path to the feature in Karate Options:

```java
@RunWith(Karate.class)
@KarateOptions(features = "classpath:animals/cats/required.feature")
public class CatsPostRunner {

}
```

2) You can run required feature or scenario adding a tag to the feature or scenario and in Karate Options:

```java
@RunWith(Karate.class)
@KarateOptions(tags = "@someTag") 
public class CatsPostRunner {

}
```

3) Also you can combine approach 1 and 2 :

```java
@RunWith(Karate.class)
@KarateOptions(features = "classpath:animals/cats/required.feature", tags = "@someTag") 
public class CatsPostRunner {

}
```

More info you find in [Karate Options](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-options).

Comment: Above will work with JUnit 4 for JUnit 5 you can create one method per scenario.